# How do I add a button component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm rendering components from an array `'values': ["hello", "world]` successfully but I would like to add a button component so that every time it gets clicked, another empty field shows up. This is what it currently looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

but i would like it so that there is a button and every time I click on it, it renders another empty component to input text. Would it be correct to add a button component directly inside the my array_node.jsx file? Is what I'm doing correct so far? Would I also have to add some sort of `newInput: function()` in side the `var AddButton = React.createClass({})`? Thank you!

**array_node.jsx:**

```
{...
    childChange: function(name, valid, value) {

        // update state
        this.state.values = this.props.values;

        // Using regex to find last digits from 0-9
        var pattern = /[0-9]/;
        var match = name.match(pattern);

        // Parse char into int
        var i = parseInt(match);

        this.state.values[i] = value;
        this.setState(this.state);

        // Call parent callback
        this.props.callback(
            this.props.name,
            this.props.node.valid(this.state.values),
            this.state.values
        );
    },
    addItem: function(values){
    },

        render: function() {
            var that = this;

            return (
                <div id = "form">
                {this.props.values.map(function(v, i) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                        {(that.props.node.get().constructor.name === "Parent") ?
                        <ParentComponent
                            name={that.props.name + i}
                            key={i}
                            timer={that.props.timer}
                            callback={that.childChange}
                            values={v}
                            newParent={that.props.node.get()}
                        />
                        :
                        <NodeComponent
                            name={that.props.name + i}
                            key={i}
                            timer={that.props.timer}
                            callback={that.childChange}
                            value={v}
                            newNode={that.props.node.get()}
                        />
                        }
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                </div>
           )
        }
    });
    return ArrayNodeComponent


var AddButton = React.createClass({
    addItem: function() {

    },

    render: function() {

        return(
        <div id="create_new_entry">

        </div>
        )
    }
})
```

**formatoc:**

```
var props = {
    'name' : 'form',
    'timer' : 1500,
    'callback' : function(id, validity, value) {console.log(id, validity, value);},
    'values': ["hello", "world"],

    'node' : new FormatOC.ArrayNode({"__array__":"unique", "__type__":"string","__minimum__":1,"__maximum__":200,"__component__":"Input"},
    )
}

React.render(React.createElement(ArrayNodeComponent, props), document.getElementById('react-component'));
```

Comment: Your code seems to be very outdated. Is there a reason you are using `React.createClass` instead of es6 classes? If you are starting to learn react I can strongly recommend to make use of the es6 syntax. I have literally nobody seen writing react code like this for ages except for some weird project requirements.

Comment: Absolutely what @trixn said, it seems that you may need to read up on some more modern examples, take a look at the react docs, they are pretty good for getting started https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might add a button into your form within the render function.
Then listen to clicks and add a new empty element to your values list.

if you would like to propagate the changes to some parent component, you would have to pass the `onClick` handler from the parent component and update the values list there too.

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

class ArrayNodeComponent extends Component {

  // other code ...
  // like your initialisation of your state
  // and other functions

  addEmptyItem() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      values: [...values, ""]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="test">
        {
          /* this is your values map routine, shortened */
          this.props.values.map(function(v, i) { /*...*/ })
        }
        <button onClick={() => this.addEmptyItem()}>Add</button>
      </form>
    );
  }

}
```

Btw in this simple scenario, it would not make sense to create a custom Button component.